# LoadBalancer Service accessed through "port" and not "nodePort"

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have enabled Kubernetes on Docker-Desktop and created a service of type LoadBalancer defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30002
```

Why can I access it through http://localhost:8081/ (using port) and not http://localhost:30002 (using nodePort)?

Comment: please share how you access and from where? (from inside other container, from outside of Kuberentes network...)

Comment: @rok from browser, using nodePort I get connection refused

Comment: Have you tried http://{node ip}:{node port}?